# Do the following sentences involving "As a ____" contain dangling modifiers?

Tags: grammar, dangling-participles

I've seen sentences along the lines of the following written quite frequently, but I'm unsure whether they would be classified as dangling modifiers, considering the noun which the modifier refers to is not positioned *too* far from the beginning of the sentence, but it nonetheless does not immediately follow the modifier. My gut feeling tells me that the following examples *are* dangling modifiers, but I'm not 100% sure:

> As **a writer**, what are some of **your** favorite motifs?
>
> As **a teacher**, who was **your** most memorable student?
>
> As **president of the United States**, how did **Roosevelt** handle the Depression?
>
> As **a student**, can **I** tutor my classmates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No

> As a student, can I tutor my classmates?

As Kasa stated, this is not misplaced at all and only takes on that appearance because of the formatting of English questions.

> As president of the United States, how did Roosevelt handle the Depression?

This is the same structure. It's a tiny bit awkward since it could theoretically be understood as asking a sitting president what his official position is about the job Roosevelt did. There are better ways to ask the same question: *Once elected...* *After taking office...* *As president...*

> As a writer, what are some of your favorite motifs?
>
> As a teacher, who was your most memorable student?

If you had a bad teacher who *really* didn't like you, you *could* get marked down for this since the clauses can be misunderstood as modifying the question words *what* and *who*. (See Kasa's answer, where s/he misunderstands them as modifying *your*.) Really, though, they're not misplaced at all and modify the entire sentence adverbially as part of your question to the listener. You could add *speaking...* *in your experience...* *in your opinion...* to the beginning to make this more explicit, but it's not necessary.

## but kinda

None of these is an example of a misplaced modifier in the sense that you mean and none of them are *wrong*, but all of them except the teaching one sound a little *more awkward* when you say it this way. It's more natural to put that clause at the end of the sentence: *Can I do this as a student?* *How did he handle it as president?* *What are your favorite Xs as a writer?*

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that these are dangling modifiers. Why you may it confusing is because these are actually questions.

Instead, consider them to be statements.

E.g.

*As a writer, my favourite motifs are..*

Now *as a writer* doesn't appear to be a dangling modifier as it is close to *my*, the pronoun it modifies.

Comment: *As a writer* doesn't modify the adjective *my*; if anything, it would modify *motifs*. Really, it's adverbial and works just as well at the end of the sentence as at the beginning.